# Woocommerce - Conditional add to cart redirect - from product page only

Tags: woocommerce

I want customers to get redirected to a specified page after clicking the add to cart button, but only from the single product page. If they click on add to cart on the shop page, I want them to remain there.

Currently I have it set up so that the add to cart button will redirect them back to the shop page. So if they're on page 3 and add a product to the cart, it will redirect them back to page 1, which is very annoying if you just want want to scroll through products and add many products without getting redirected to shop page 1 or the cart each time you add a product.

I can't seem to find a solution for this anywhere, so if someone could point me in the right direction, I'd be very grateful.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit confused by your question but I'll share some code that may be helpful.

Here is how to check if you are on the product page:

```
function b2bking_product_redirection_to_account() {
        if (!is_user_logged_in()){  
            if ( ! is_product() ) return; // Only for single product pages.
                wp_redirect( get_permalink( wc_get_page_id( 'myaccount' ) ) ); // redirect home.
            exit();
        }
    }
```

> which is very annoying if you just want want to scroll through
>   products and add many products without getting redirected to shop page
>   1 or the cart each time you add a product.

Isn't this something you should be doing in JavaScript? You could get the current page:
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window_location.asp

Then check (if page === X) {run_redirect();}